# Use shiro1.8, session memory leak, frequent fullgc！

Tags: shiro, tomcat9

I use shiro in my project, but after the program runs for a period of time, fullgc is frequent. I generated a dump file and found that there are a large number of "standradSession" classes, which cannot be cleared by gc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwQ0s.png)

doubt:
Shiro uses the redirection function to access the non-existent interface, as if the current session information will be saved before the jump, as shown in the figure.
Is it related to shutting down the daemon thread that cleans up seesion that comes with tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this probably has more to do with the type of Session management you are using. Are you using the in-memory session management from Shiro or Tomcat?
If not, how are your sessions stored and what does the cache or TTL look like for them?

I'm not fully following your doubt though, you may want to add an edit to explain how your web application sessions are configured, the type of load you are seeing, etc.

More info on Shiro's Session Management: https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html